# how to change z axis of sphere when camera changes its position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I wanted to create virtual tour app like roundme.com and I was creating a functionality allowing a user to move camera on mouse move (not click). If you visit roundme.com, it is possible to rotate camera by clicking & dragging as well as move camera on mouse move. So, to achieve mouse move effect, I decided to shake or, say, move sphere itself instead of camera whenever a user moves mouse. But when I rotate camera by clicking and & dragging and then move mouse to see shake effect then it shakes weirdly because when the project initially starts the camera looks exactly at z axis but when I rotate sphere then the camera no longer looks at z axis straight. I think the solution can be to ensure that even if I rotate camera then the camera should look at z axis so that shake effect works properly. Is there any way for me to achieve that?

Comment: Please include the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The website you've referenced appears to be not working due to certificate issues, as all of the links to the resources start with `https://`